# Is there a way to save multiple images to an array in python for later use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, opencv

I am using opencv python. I have a nested for loop that generates an image with each iteration. Is there a way to save these images to an array for view later or a way to save each one individually through each iteration?

Comment: I assume that creating a list `images = []` outside of the loop and appending it during the loop `images.append(image)` is all that you need.

Comment: Great I will try that. Sorry also new to python so when I do that. How do I access the images individually later?

Comment: You can loop through the list: `for img in images:` Or you can access its individual items: `first_img = images[0]`, `second_img = images[1]` I assume the first option is what you're after.

Comment: You can read about python lists here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/

Comment: Right but can I still show the image that way? Like to see the actual image not just the array values

Comment: Edit your question and put your code in there (at least the loop which generates the image) and I'll be able to help you more precisely.

Comment: All you need to do is probably `for img in images: cv2.imshow('name', img)` Might need to add a `sleep()` function in the loop so that it doesn't go by too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use simply [append()](https://towardsdatascience.com/append-in-python-41c37453400) function to add your each image to an array.

Let assume you have some images in the file in ***.jpg** format. In a loop you can read each image and append them to an array. After loop done, you can call desired image from array and show them with `imshow()`

Here is an example code:

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np


image_array = [] // array which ll hold the images
files = glob.glob ("*.jpg")
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    image_array.append (image) // append each image to array
// this will print the channel number, size, and number of images in the file
print('image_array shape:', np.array(image_array).shape) 

cv2.imshow('frame', image_array[0])

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: So say I have nested for loops(sorry can't post the code at work right now) but  for example:                         
for x in range(0,10,1) then for y in range (0,3,1) and I want to save the image for through each iteration of the loops. Can I access the image based on the x and y like I want to see the image where x = 3 and y = 2? If so how can I do it?